# Can we apply thermodynamics processes for real gas too? And how

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, adiabatic

Like in adiabatic process there is closed system but in reality we know there is no such thing as closed system there will be still exchange of heat so it will not work adiabatically means it is only applicable for ideal gas not real gas?

Comment: In reality there are no apples or oranges, either, just try to define what an apple is in an absolute sense. Speaking more thermodynamically, in your sense there are no macroscopic "masses" because all solids sublimate and at any instant molecules come and go, so what is 1 gram of anything?

Comment: For the record you are talking about isolated systems, not closed systems. Closed systems do permit energy transfer, while isolate systems do not.

Comment: Voting to reopen. Question is detailed, clear *and* has a good answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The laws and processes of thermodynamics aren't just for ideal gases. They also apply to real substances like actual gases, solids, and liquids. However, ideal gases come up often in thermodynamics because they're easier to work with, and many phenomena can be closely approximated using an ideal gas model.

Just to clarify a few points you've mentioned:

- An adiabatic process is a thermodynamic process in which there is no heat exchange with the surroundings. It doesn't mean that the system has to be absolutely isolated from its environment. It simply means there's no net heat exchange. Note that both ideal and real gases can undergo adiabatic processes.
- Thermodynamic laws/processes aren't just about gases. For instance, the first law (conservation of energy) and the second law (entropy increases) apply universally. Concepts like isothermal, adiabatic, isochoric, and isobaric processes; phase changes; and entropy changes are relevant for solids, liquids, and real gases.